# counting duplicates in ruby array and storing in hash

Tags: mysql, ruby, arrays, hash

I have a array coming from a mysql query like this

```
section, views
aa, 2
aa, 100
bb, 2
bb, 3
bb, 100
```

and I am using this code to sort it

```
b = Hash.new(0)
array.each do |row|
  ....
  ....
  b[section] += 1
end
```

which currently gives me a result hash for `b[2]`

```
aa,2
bb,3
```

Now I want the mysql query to filter the views for smaller and larger than 50 for example and would like the result to be

```
section,small,large
aa,1,1
bb,2,1
```

How do I implement this? Or would it be easier to do something like this:

```
aa_small,1
aa_large,1
bb_small,2
bb_large,1
```

i.e. keep them as separate hashes?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you need something like:

```
views = 
    [['aa', 2],
     ['aa', 100],
     ['bb', 2],
     ['bb', 3],
     ['bb', 100]]

views
  .group_by(&:first)
  .map { |v, vs| [v, vs.partition { |_, x| x < 50 }
                       .map(&:length)] }
# => [["aa", [1, 1]], ["bb", [2, 1]]]
```

or if you want Hash:

```
Hash[views
       .group_by(&:first)
       .map { |v, vs| [v, vs.partition { |_, x| x < 50 }
                            .map(&:length)] }]
# => {"aa"=>[1, 1], "bb"=>[2, 1]}
```